# Background Image Wont Show

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get this style to work for the body of the HTML page, it works when the style is applied within the  tags but not when used with an external style sheet.

**CSS** Doesn't work with this code.

```
body {
    background-image:url(img/geometric.jpg);
}
```

**HTML** Works here.

```
<body style="background-image:url('img/geometric.jpg');">  
</body>
```

I want to use external styling for the whole page. I'm curious on how to fix this odd issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path to the image must be relative to the CSS file that references it, not the HTML file that it will appear in.